# JavaScript on Visual Studio Code - is Node required to run a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I am currently trying to catch up with some JS basics, before continuing with my node.js-project.

I wanted to execute the file and kept getting the error 'console is not defined', when I wanted to use `console.log('Hello!')`

The only helpful way to run the file normally was with: `node ./myjsfile.js`

I installed node.js for that node project.

But for just running super basic JavaScript I don't want node.js.

What are better (lighter!) ways to run my JavaScript files inside Visual Studio Code?
Like what's the most basic way to do it?

Comment: JS, like every other scripting language, needs an engine to actually run code. So that's either node.js as a "universal programming language" engine with a standard library API, or you can run the .js inside a browser if you're writing client code. But yeah: you need something to run that JS code. The simplest is "install node from nodejs.org" and then in VS code opening a CLI (ctrl-backtick)  and then running your file with `node filename.js`.